# Audacity select multiple ranges at same time for deleting

Tags: audacity, cutting

I am editing a audio file where someone has given me start/stop times to cut out of the file. However once I cut one out the whole timeline shifts making the rest of the start/stop times incorrect. I am new to editing audio so it might have a name but there has to be something that handles a situation like this I would assume? Can someone point me to the right function or place on how to handle cutting out multiple time ranges for the same file. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To  do it one marker at a time, without messing up the ones you haven't yet done, start with the last marker & work towards the beginning.

This assume that once you've done a cut, you no longer need the marker.

Comment: Thanks I actually woke up thinking of doing it this way like light-bulb!

Answer (score 2):

Consider replacing the sections with silence or with a low-level tone that will be easy to re-locate. When done go back and delete those sections.

To replace, highlight the section and choose `Generate... Silence`